# Partiton RDBMS ( DB2 ) table data either by SQL query or Java

Tags: java, sql, db2, spring-batch, partitioning

I have to implement a partitioning for the column data ( Column Name : `ID` ) for a very large database table ( DB2 ). Table has more than a billion rows and keeps growing.

Partitioning has to be implemented like [illustrated here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/) i.e. I have to calculate minId & maxId for a specified range.

ID column values are unique but not sequential so simple approach as illustrated in above link will not work - i.e. starting from an ID then keep adding range.

```
WITH ROWNUMTAB AS ( 
 SELECT ROWNUM, ID FROM ( 
   SELECT rownumber() over (order by ID) as ROWNUM, ID 
   FROM IDTABLE  
 ) 
 WHERE mod(ROWNUM,1000)=0 OR mod(ROWNUM,1000)=1  WITH UR  
)  
SELECT T1.ID AS MIN_ID  , T2.ID AS MAX_ID 
FROM ROWNUMTAB T1 
INNER JOIN ROWNUMTAB T2 
  ON T1.ROWNUM+999=T2.ROWNUM 
WITH UR;
```

This above query gives me `MIN_ID,MAX_ID` for a particular range - 1000.

This query works for small tables but for a very large table having few billion rows, assigning a row number to each row is not completing in realistic time.

Any alternate suggestions to achieve this kind of partitioning?

Challenge is described [here](https://victorjabur.com/2014/11/10/spring-batch-partitioner-case-study-with-sourcecode-best-practices/) too.

Reading all `ID` values into memory then doing Java manipulation is not a feasible option either.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why do you think that batches of non-uniform sizes is a problem?

Comment: Its about overall throughput of multiple Java threads running in parallel. If N parallel threads get asymmetric data, program throughput is very less compared to when those threads works on similar count.

Comment: Can't you restart the thread that finishes early with another batch?

Comment: No, in Java a thread can't be restarted. Number of threads and which threads process which records is a job static meta data that gets set up at job start.

Comment: Using a recyclable stateless thread pool is another option and that would do what you are suggesting but that hasn't worked out well for me in Spring Batch.